# neural networks in pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I am using pytorch and need to implement this as a part of a neural network. Is there a particular way to code the layers shown in purple (s
def forward(self, images: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
x= self.fc1(x)
return x

Comment: What is your current code? The basic idea can be that you have a custom `forward` function like [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/examples_nn/two_layer_net_module.html), which takes some input, passes it through first layer, than you split its result into two parts manually, find maximum and send it to the next linear layer

Comment: it is better to update your question and wrap the code in  ```

Comment: how would you suggest dividing the data manually?

Comment: you have a tensor of shape [batch_size, 4608], you can use `torch.split` [function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.split.html) to make two tensors of size [batch_size, 2304]

Comment: many thanks for the idea. is there a particular function for max? torch.max deals with one tensor whilst I need to deal with two tensors in a tuple

Comment: you can consider `torch.maximum` [link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.maximum.html) it will return maximum element from each tensor , but I'm not sure what is _max_ of the tensors in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining all my comments into the answer.

To split the output vector from the first layer, which has a shape `[batch_size, 4608]`, you can use `torch.split` [function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.split.html) as follows

```
batch = torch.zeros((10, 4608))
sub_batch_1, sub_batch_2 = torch.split(batch, 2304, dim=1)
print(sub_batch_1.shape, sub_batch_2.shape)
```

This code results in two tensors

```
(torch.Size([10, 2304]), torch.Size([10, 2304]))
```

I am not sure about **MAX** logic you need. If it is about getting the maximum element in a given position from two tensors obtained during `split`, then `torch.maximum` [function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.maximum.html) can be used to do so.

Comment: thank you. the maximum refers to the maximum activation level. used to reduce overfitting

Comment: then you probably want something like [maxpooling](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#pooling-layers), but I'm not sure how to do it right with 2 inputs.